# YC startup has not delivered equity to me 6 months later

Tags: contracts, startup, tech-industry, equity

I worked for a YC startup for a few months, and we had a contract in which they promised me X number of shares, delivered monthly, for my work with them. Each month, they failed to deliver (via certificate, Carta, etc.) these shares to me, citing excuses.

Eventually, the relationship ended because no shares had been delivered and I was interested in transitioning to cash compensation.

As I understand, they have internal difficulties getting their equity structure in proper order to formally deliver shares to anyone in the company, not just me. My manager, for example, did not have any shares in concrete form, either, when I left--just promises in contract form.

I've maintained contact with the company they have continued to delay and make up excuses for about 6 months now.

I had fun writing a little code for them but I feel disrespected. I'd like to compel them to deliver these shares to me as compensation for my work, even though they are likely worthless.

Furthermore, it seems interesting to me that they are having internal issues making delivery of shares to anyone in the company challenging. Since I'm not the only one, I feel this is quite irregular and improper, but I am not an expert on corporate equity structure. I wonder if this information can somehow be helpful in compelling them to deliver shares to me.

Any thoughts or suggestions on a path forward here?

Comment: Hire an attorney.

Comment: @sf02 Would an attorney be interested in a situation where only equity was involved? I would rather not pay out of pocket for obtaining equity that has uncertain value, unless the attorney can be compensated on the backend somehow.

Comment: If you are not willing to pay an attorney then they likely would not be interested in helping you out.

Comment: @sf02 Attorneys are sometimes compensated through contingency fees that rely on prevailing against the other party.

Comment: Correct, and since you admittedly don't know the value of what you're trying to recover they couldn't possibly know how much they might be compensated.

Comment: @sf02 You first told me to hire an attorney, but now steer towards a different conclusion that it isn't worth it for me to hire one and that no attorney would be interested, so what are you saying?

Comment: I never said it was not worth it for you, I said it may not be worth it for them assuming they are paid based on what they recover.

Comment: @sf02 This information is not helpful.

Comment: Did you put a “back door” or “kill switch” in your code?

Comment: @SolarMike Nope! :)

Comment: That will be a lesson learnt then.

Comment: I think it's not so much that @sf02 is not offering helpful advice as that you don't have a lot of alternatives. The courts and the legal system are the primary tool for dealing with contract disputes and almost inevitably require legal representation. That makes no sense if the damages that can be recovered are less than the cost of asserting your rights. Check your contract to see if mediation is mandated in disputes (mediation is sometimes less expensive then a court battle). As suggested in a comment by Gh0stFish later on, you might get in touch with YC to see if they're interested.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant True, definitely recognize that I don't have many options here and that the true remedy would have been to not be in the situation at all. As it stands I'm looking for a reasonable direction on how to escalate or encourage their compliance with our contract. It is a matter of principle and ethics to me, as I was advising them on the side in exchange for their equity. There was an element of good faith here and it was violated. Thanks for your response.

Comment: "As I understand, they have internal difficulties getting their equity structure in proper order to formally deliver shares to anyone in the company, not just me." And yet, they received funding through YC, so YC got some shares I assume. Right?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk That's an interesting point. This is what they told me, but what you said also makes sense. I wonder what's really going on.

Comment: @septimyr, If you do decide to hire a lawyer, have all the people affected chip in to pay for that lawyer. Does the startup have competitors? Or large clients? Maybe you could sell your future claims to such a third party and wash your hands of the entire thing.

Comment: What is a YC startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be better answered on a legal help forum, as that is what you're interested in - legally (I hope) compelling this company to deliver what they owe to you.

I agree with your comments that there's no point in hiring an attorney. It might make sense to get a free consultation to at least go over your options with someone who knows what they're talking about though. For a young startup, the threat of a realistic lawsuit from someone who sounds serious about it could very well be enough to make them cough up your shares, even if you would never spend the resources to actually sue them. Young startups do **not** want to be in litigation.

The only other thing I got for you is to threaten to report them to your country's regulatory agency that deals with wage theft, or something like the American BBB, and see if that gets you anywhere. Or look into actually reporting them to such an organization, but I'm not sure how likely that is to result in your gain vs. just their loss.

Finally, if you decide to leave it be, you may want to at least look into what kind of time limit you have to legally fight this before the statute runs out - say it's three years, then you can check in after around 2 1/2 years and if the company has somehow gotten super valuable, you could fight for your now valuable assets before time runs out.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was looking for: thoughts on next steps and some direction—I didn't know about the regulatory options, for example. Good to keep in mind the possible time limit if they make it big later. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @septimyr as well as regulatory bodies, it might be worth reaching out to YC as well. They may not have legal power to do anything about it, but they do have their own reputation to protect and may have some leverage.

Comment: @Gh0stFish Interesting idea!

Comment: And hiring an attorney to write the threatening letter about reporting to BBB etc can be worth the cost.

Comment: @PeterM BBB has been under a fair amount of [criticism in the last decade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Business_Bureau), and a bad BBB rating would be meaningless to a YC startup company. Gh0stFish's comment about contacting YC would be more to the point. The company will have a contract with YC and YC has the legal muscle at their finger tips to make a credible threat.

Comment: @inBedded16 the state regulatory agencies will only be interested if the OP can make a case that they were a wage employee. It sounds like they were a contractor. In which case the remedy is to take them to court and sue for enforcement of the contract. As pretty much everyone agrees, this probably is not worth the candle.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant This is correct, I was a contractor. We had a written agreement for equity compensation only; I was not under W2. Appreciate your comments and perspective, thanks.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant I only mentioned BBB because InBedded mentioned it in their answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Any thoughts or suggestions on a path forward here?

Yes, after 6 months of not getting paid in full, stop working until you are paid in full. If you don't care enough about your compensation, neither will they.

Comment: Yes, the working relationship did end for the reason you stated.

Comment: @septimyr then move on with your life. Lawyers and lawsuits especially are expensive.

Comment: A startup that is having trouble paying shares is not likely to _ever_ be in a position to compensate anyone. They are not likely to ever get investor money. Consider the time spent as "tuition" on an important lesson. Ask better questions and be aware the next time you get into an agreement with a startup.

Comment: @DavidR Makes sense, any thoughts on specific questions? I asked what I believe to be standard questions that have served me well in the past (I'm mid-career): e.g. "What's your runway?", "What's your funding look like?", "How many shares exist in total?", etc. If everything looks OK for these, it seems difficult to properly vet a company without coming off as deeply distrustful and paranoid (which works against you in building rapport). This isn't to say that I couldn't have done better though, and I am curious if you have suggestions on how to do better next time.

Comment: @DavidR - As you point out. If the company cannot pay what is practically is worthless shares until they are actually worth something, then the company has more problems, then just not compensating their employees. The reason they likely paid with share equity, instead of a monetary compensation, is they have no actual monetary equity. Yes, those shares are only worth, what someone would have been willing to pay for them.

Comment: @septimyr The time to ask hard questions starts when they don't pay the first month. If you are comfortable with the answers at that time, harder questions get asked the second month and that is when to stop work. Questions such as: why are you unable to pay essentially worthless shares? If they are unable to pay a lawyer enough to generate share certificates, they won't have the money to do anything. Run.

Answer (score 1):

A long shot might be filing a complaint with the [California Department of Financial Protection and Innovation](https://dfpi.ca.gov/submit-a-complaint/), or maybe the [SEC](https://tcr.sec.gov/TcrExternalWeb/faces/pages/accept.jspx). Inducing you to perform labor through the promise of securities (stock) that are never delivered *might* be a form of securities fraud. The difficulty would be determining which is the appropriate agency, and whether there is a violation of sufficient seriousness to justify the cost of enforcement.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. It is true that they are located in CA. I performed the work remotely from WA though, if that's relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the sort of detail that might need a lawyer to sort out. The contract should specify which jurisdiction it is under though.